# Handling 404 Error Response with Async/Await

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios, try-catch, openweathermap

I am working on a weather app and need to properly handle a 404 response from the server. There are 2 API requests made with the second one needing data from the first one.

I basically want to render "location does not exist" when there is a 404 error response. An attempt was made with [try..catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) which resulted in this issue: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'coord')`.

Error happens for both success and failure responses.
[image: success response]
[image: failure response]

Questions:

- What does this error mean and how can I properly de-structure `coord` prop?
- How can I properly setup try..catch to handling error response?
- Bonus question: how can try..catch be made inside `getForecastData` function as well?

Here is the **useForecast.js** file containing logic and API calls:

- try...catch attempt was made in `getCoordinates` function

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5";
const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

const useForecast = () => {
  // const [forecast, setForecast] = useState(null)
  // const [isError, setError] = useState(false)

  const getCoordinates = async (location) => {
    try {
      //try statement
      const { data } = await axios(`${BASE_URL}/weather`, {
        params: { q: location.value, appid: API_KEY }
      });
      console.log("call is successful", data);
    } catch (data) {
      //catch statement
      if (!data.ok) {
        console.log("location does not exist", data.message);
        return;
      }
      return data;
    }
  };

  const getForecastData = async (lat, lon) => {
    const { data } = await axios(`${BASE_URL}/onecall`, {
      params: { lat: lat, lon: lon, appid: API_KEY }
    });

    //if no data is not returned, call setError("Something went wrong") and return

    return data;
  };

  const submitRequest = async (location) => {
    const response = await getCoordinates(location);
    const { lat, lon } = response.coord;

    if (!response || !lat || !lon) return;
    console.log("getCoordinates call will render", { response });

    const data = await getForecastData(lat, lon);
    if (!data) return;
    console.log("getForecastData call will render", { data });
  };

  return {
    submitRequest
  };
};

export default useForecast;
```

Here is a stripped down version of the app(where screen shots were generated from): https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-pare-uc65ee?file=/src/useForecast.js

**Note:** API key has been removed for privacy reasons(sorry for the inconvenience)

Lastly, for context I am using the follow with React in app:

- OpenWeather API: https://openweathermap.org/
- Axios: https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: The "return data;" statement in `getCoordinates` should be outside of the catch statement, otherwise your function doesn't return anything

Comment: @Houssam Thanks for the suggestion. Moving `return data` outside of `try` block will result in `'data' is not defined`. Any insight into restructuring the try..catch to account for this? `finally` statement perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to suggestions from @Houssam and @ale917k adjustments also had to be made with conditionals in `submitRequest`.

All adjustments made were:

1. placing `return data` inside `try` block
2. appending `|| {}` to response
3. changing first if statement to `if(!response.coord)` then de-structure lat and lon.

Codebase with changes:

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5";
const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

const useForecast = () => {
  // const [forecast, setForecast] = useState(null)
  // const [isError, setError] = useState(false)

  const getCoordinates = async (location) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios(`${BASE_URL}/weather`, {
        params: { q: location.value, appid: API_KEY }
      });
      console.log("call is successful", data);
      //adjustment 1
      return data;
    } catch (data) {
      if (!data.ok) {
        console.log("location does not exist");
        return;
      }
    }
  };

  const getForecastData = async (lat, lon) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios(`${BASE_URL}/onecall`, {
        params: { lat: lat, lon: lon, appid: API_KEY }
      });
      return data;
    } catch (data) {
      if (!data.ok) {
        console.log("something went wrong");
        return;
      }
    }
  };

  const submitRequest = async (location) => {
    const response = (await getCoordinates(location)) || {}; //adjustment 2
    //adjustment 3
    if (!response.coord) return;

    const { lat, lon } = response.coord;
    const data = await getForecastData(lat, lon);

    if (!data) return;
  };

  return {
    submitRequest
  };
};

export default useForecast;
```

Screenshot of success and failure logs:
[image: success and failure logs]

Answer (score 1):

You're catching the error successfully. The problem is that when it happens, you are not returning any value to

```js
const response = await getCoordinates(location);
```

`response` will then be undefined, and `coord` will therefore trigger the error since `undefined` values can't hold any property.

To fix it, you can use the classic safety as below:

```js
const response = await getCoordinates(location) || {};
```

Which essentially will make `response` always an object, successful or not

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and suggestion. Including `|| {}` still does not fix the issue with `response` being undefined when the call is successful. Would this have anything to do with the `return data` placement in the try...catch?